# Ruby rails how to create a file with specific encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, encoding

My work is create a .csv file with gb2312 file encoding to download,code below:

```
csv = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{Time.now.to_i}.csv"
handler = File.open(csv, 'w:gb2312')
handler.puts ... # write some data 

handler.close
send_file csv, :type =>  'application/csv; charset=gb2312'
```

As you see, first create a .csv file in tmp folder, then write data ,finally send to browser.I have tried set encoding here and there, but it can't work ,the file encoding is always utf-8,not any others. my rails is 1.8.7, earnest to your help. thx

Comment: Is the local version at `"#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{Time.now.to_i}.csv"` correct, and the file in the browser incorrect, or are they both wrong?

Comment: Hi Brad, they are both wrong...

Comment: Weird... it looks right... Have you tried `'w:GB2312'`?

Comment: try the GB, but still inncorrect... :(  fuzzy

Comment: is the data, that you are writing, encoded in that specific encoding? otherwise you could try String.encode for that.